# House plant identification with smooth leaves

Tags: identification, houseplants

I saw this plant at my brother's place, can anyone identify this house plant? It has a bit smooth feeling leaves, with a point downwards.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Peperomia, specifically Peperomia polybotrya, probably the variety 'Jayde', pictured lower down in this link https://www.bhg.com/gardening/plant-dictionary/houseplant/peperomia/ along with general care instructions. There is one very similar called P. polybotrya 'Raindrop', but it most  closely resembles 'Jayde'.

Comment: Thank you, it looks indeed exactly like the Jayde Peperomia. The same shiny leaves with teardrop-shape.